# unable to redeploy web application on glassfish3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I m trying to deploy a web application using netbeans to glassfish 3.01 but i m not able to do so

Glassfish says

Inconsistent Module State

the web app has some jars and a ejb jar for a local ejb

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error message from the glassfish server log?

Answer (score 4):

Open the domain.xml file that you will find in this folder:

"your glassfish installation"/domains/"your domain"/config

In this file look for your application deployment configuration to manually remove it:

1) Remove the web-module tag

```
<applications>
...
<web-module availability-enabled="false" context-root="yourapplicatoinContext" ... />
 ...
</applications>
```

2) Also remove the application-ref to your application:

```
<server config-ref="server-config" lb-weight="100" name="server">
 ...
   <application-ref ... ref="your application name" ... />
 ... 
</server>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I had a webapp that would never undeploy for some reason.  One thing though, you didn't mention the actual file name to change: domain.xml

Comment: that's the answer but if you are on glassfish 4 I answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061541/undeployment-gives-the-error-application-not-registered-glassfish/40013585#40013585

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

- undeploy
- stop Glassfish
- start Glassfish
- deploy

If you can't undeploy, try the other steps anyway. If you don't have any luck, you could try it this way:

- stop Glassfish
- edit domain.xml (probably in domains/domain1/config)- back it up first; remove all references to your app (probably under application / application-ref); just make sure it's still valid xml
- start Glassfish
- deploy

It should have solved it. If still no luck anyway, remove every file or directory related to your app, probably under domains/domain1/generated and domains/domain1/applications/....

You could always recreate a new domain, but above steps will solve your problem.

You could be in such a situation after stopping Glassfish middle in a deploiyment, for example.

Comment: i had to go for rolling back to a fresh installation of glassfish 3.1 wihtout the latest updates...

Comment: Did you try above steps? It should have solved it. Reinstalling glassfish shouldn't be necessery, just create a new domain if needed. Actually, I think it is better to understand the problem when possible, reinstalling or recreating a domain just wipes it out. It can come back since you don't know the reason or how to fix it.

Comment: ya i tried the steps especially deleting the app generated folders... but that didn't solve the problem... may be i missed out some other folder...btw if i had to do it everytime i m deploying i would be screwed as i was hot deploying a app on save and it gets deployed everytime i save a file... and above that i didnt find any solutions in the glassfish forums too.. they shouldnt had brought a update without testing it... and without any or no support in the forums... its a disaster for production environs..

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are really extreme. There is no need to create a new domain or re-install if you cannot redeploy your web application during development.

If you app is very complex, then consider scripting any clean up needed in a Production environment. The below steps will keep you up and working in the short term.

To re-deploy a web app to a single domain on Glassfish 3.1, do the following:

- Stop Glassfish from the command line.
- Delete all the files in the following directories:

> glassfish\domains\domain1\generated 
>   glassfish\domains\domain1\applications

- Start Glassfish from the command line.
- Deploy your app via the Admin Tool or command line.

Answer (score 0):

In Glassfish 5, I searched for my `app name` in the `domain.xml` and deleted all the tags mentioning it. There was one occurence in the beginning (`<system-applications>`) and one at the end at approx. line 460 (`<applications>`). Then `redeploy` worked!