# cannot accept a NULL value on @ID @generatedvalue JPA entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to make a add to wish list feature for my app but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):           org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'WISH_ID'        cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO WISHLIST (BOOK_TITLE, CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(dukesbookstore.entity.Wishlist[ wishId=null ])
```

ENTITY class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WISHLIST")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries(
{
@NamedQuery(name = "Wishlist.findByCustomerId", query = "SELECT w FROM Wishlist w WHERE  w.customerId = :customerId"),

})
public class Wishlist implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name = "WISH_ID")
private Integer wishId;
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Integer customerId;
@Size(max = 35)
@Column(name = "BOOK_TITLE")
private String bookTitle;

public Wishlist()
{
}



public Integer getCustomerId()
{
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId)
{
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getBookTitle()
{
    return bookTitle;
}

public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle)
{
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
}   
}
```

and this is the code for creating a new wish:

```
public void createWishlist(String title,int cust_id)
{
            Wishlist newWish = new Wishlist();
            newWish.setBookTitle(title);
            newWish.setCustomerId(cust_id);
            em.persist(newWish);
  }
```

I tried to look at other similar problems but they involves hibernate which i am not using. I have also tried various generation strategy such as `AUTO`,`SEQUENCE`,`TABLE` but all failed. I also have another entity named customer which is exactly same but it works fine though its created from a form.

Changing to `AUTO` generates this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.
Error Code: -1
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.
root cause

org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.
```

**Persistence.xml incase relevant**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myStorePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>mydb</jta-data-source>
    <class>myStore.entity.Book</class>
    <class>myStore.entity.Customer</class>
    <class>myStore.entity.Wishlist</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>

         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: What is the underlying database you use? Concerning ID generation, this differs, e.g. Oracle does not support GenerationType.IDENTITY. I know you said, that you tried the others, but still this may be important, in order to use it correctly.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595432/eclipselink-jpa-gets-error-when-inserting-into-derby-table-with-generated-primar) helps you?

Comment: in that post he solved it by deleting an old jar getting deployed with the entity classes from before any change to use identity generation but how do i find that old jar? so i can delete it too.

Comment: Depends on what you use for your application deployment. Usually, your application server has a deploy folder where your application gets into, so for example in JBoss its per default in jboss/server/default/deploy.

Comment: I am using ant, glassfish and netbeans for this.

Comment: "Run > Clean and Build Project" should usually do the trick. If it does not help, try any of the suggestions in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361193/unable-to-redeploy-web-application-on-glassfish3)

Comment: Other than that, I don't really see an error in your code. I would suggest to take AUTO mode in order to let eclipse link choose the right thing for your database.

Comment: changing to AUTO generates above error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is working now,

firstly, i had to delete the table that I created from netbeans db creation tool, which had a creation code like this, as seen by using "grab structure"

```
create table "APP".WISHLIST
(
WISH_ID NUMERIC(5) not null primary key,
CUSTOMER_ID NUMERIC(5),
BOOK_TITLE VARCHAR(100)
)
```

secondly, I added this code into my persistence.xml file

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

This solved the problem as it created the table by it self, which have different creation code, as seen from its grab structure from auto creation:

```
create table "APP".WISHLIST
(
WISH_ID INTEGER default GENERATED_BY_DEFAULT not null primary key,
CUSTOMER_ID NUMERIC(5),
BOOK_TITLE VARCHAR(100)
)
```

So, basically should let netbeans create the table itself from entity but i was using "Create entity from table" features, for that i had to create the tables first in netbeans gui.

Thank you @Geziefer for all the help, I learned quite a bit from your help too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a ["Non nullable attributes" in JPA single-table-inheritance problem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Common_Problems). It might help and doesn't hurt to specify

```
@JoinTable(name = "[some join table name]",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "[some ID column name]")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "[some different ID column name]")})
```