# Undeployment gives the error: Application not registered (Glassfish)

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish-4

I undeployed my APP by using the web gui of Glassfish. But if I press undeploy for my actual APP nothing happend. In my Log File a new error occurs: Application not registered (severe).
How can I undeploy my APP now correctly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a simple answer:

1. remove all references to your app from domain.xml (in glassfish/glassfish/domains/yourDomain/config/) (see also [unable to redeploy web application on glassfish3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361193))
2. remove directory glassfish/glassfish/domains/yourDomain/applications/yourAPP
3. remove all files in glassfish/glassfish/domains/yourDomain/generated/*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, tried what mr.wolle suggested but on step 1 I couldn't really find the web module as suggested in the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361193/unable-to-redeploy-web-application-on-glassfish3) , not sure if it's because I'm using glassfish 4 or because I uploaded  my app to "/" in the context-root

So I did the following:

1. searched for my app name using ctrl + w (a bit troublesome on windows since it just suggesting to close the window so did it on my mac).
2. deleted the first result which is a single line with your app name, mine is "login":

   ```
   <application-ref ref="login" virtual-servers="server"></application-ref>
   ```
3. deleted all of the following lines which is related to my "login" app:

   ```
   <application context-root="/" object-type="user" name="login"  location="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applications/login/">
       <property name="archiveType" value="war"></property>
       <property name="implicitCdiEnabled" value="true"></property>
       <property name="preserveAppScopedResources" value="false"></property>
       <property name="appLocation" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applications/__internal/login/login7312386559419533277.war"></property>
       <property name="defaultAppName" value="login7312386559419533277"></property>
       <module name="login">
           <engine sniffer="security"></engine>
           <engine sniffer="web"></engine>
       </module>
   </application>
   ```
4. tried to undeploy (not sure if that had any effect)
5. reset the server - done, the app *.war file was deleted (again not sure if it was due to stage 4 or not so just try it).